# Can't find the MVC 3 Html.BeginForm Expression overload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, lambda

In an MVC3 (razor) web app, I want to use the expression syntax for begin form, ex. @Html.BeginForm(c => c.ActionName(null)). However, I don't see an overload that takes an expression and the page throws an error when I try it.

Am I forgetting a step? Do I need to include an additional namespace, or some 3rd party resource? I'm using MvcContrib.FluentHtml, but I don't see it in there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda overload of `BeginForm` is part of ASP.NET MVC Futures, which for MVC 3 can be downloaded here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! On a side note I couldn't use @Html.BeginForm<>(), I had to use @using(Html.BeginForm<>()) {.